# Dropdown menu in multiple pages using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css, menu

I had a drop down menu, that I need to use in multiple pages , is there any way to code the dropdown menu in someother page and use that in multiple pages. (Something like when I click on image a dropdown menu must appear, I had same image in multiple pages, when I click that image a dropdown menu must display)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/exuY9/1/

```
<ul id="container">

    <li class="draggable">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>1</h1>
            <div class="button"></div>
            <div class="button dropmenu"  id="menuwrap">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown"><img src="../images/Forward.JPG"></a>
                <ul class="menucontainer" style="margin:0px" id="dr1">
                    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="button"></div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="draggable">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>2</h1>
            <div class="button minimize"></div>
            <div class="button dropmenu" id="menuwrap2">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown"><img src="../images/Forward.JPG"></a>
                <ul class="menucontainer" style="margin:0px" id="dr2">
                    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="button maximize"></div>
        </div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that by removing the existing menu in both elements and place just one instance of `menucontainer` at the bottom of your page,

```
<ul class="menucontainer" style="display:none;">
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then with jQuery you append a clone of that element to each `dropmenu` element...

```
$(".dropmenu").append( $(".menucontainer").clone() );
```

I edited your fiddle to show how this works: http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/bHJvs/
I removed all the unused stuff, to show just what you asked...

---

There's another way to do this, if you don't want to have that block of HTML code hidden in the bottom of your page, you can just add the element with jQuery:

```
$(".dropmenu").append( $('<ul class="menucontainer"><li><a href="#">One</a></li><li><a href="#">Two</a></li><li><a href="#">Three</a></li></ul>') );`
```